# exception while sending the date field from json

Tags: java, json, date

I am getting an error while sending the Date field from json.

Pojo class:

```
public class Employee {

    @Column(name="created_date")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
    private Date createdDate;

    ....
}

{
   "createdDate" : "2018-07-10"
}
```

Error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-07-10": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-07-10": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"

```
{
   "createdDate" : "2018-07-10 12:45:59.000"
}
```

Error:

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2018-07-10 12:45:59.000": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2018-07-10 12:45:59.000": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"

How can I solve this error?

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: I’ve heard it said that you should use `LocalDate` instead of `Date` and then [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). In any case the `Date` class has design problems and is long outdated.

Comment: @Ole - did not work.

Answer (score 3):

you are expecting this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000` and you receive this `yyyy-MM-dd`. You have to receive something like this `2018-07-10 12:45:59.000` or change your accepted format to `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: I am getting the same error:

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-07-10 12:45:59.000": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000 "; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-07-10 12:45:59.000": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000

Comment: @Amit try to use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. I changed .000 to .SSS